# How to compile a npm module into a browser script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, browserify

I want to customize the Parse SDK. They provide source through an [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse), which makes it usable in node environments.

How can I compile this node module into a standalone `parse.js` script which will run as it is on a browser?

I tried using `browserify` as

```
browserify ./parse -o parse.js
```

but the `parse.js` it spits out is quite large and still contains node remanents: `process` and `require` commands. Although it executes without any error on browser, the browser cannot find `Parse` definition.

Comment: It's large because it adds browser [compatible `process`](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#compatibility) and so on. What do you have in `parse.js`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the correct way to compile the parse npm module into a browser script is to use:

```
browserify path/to/npm/parse --standalone parse > parse-browser.js
```

For any other script it should  be :

```
browserify path_to_module --standalone global_name_to_expose > output.js
```

Also, since the parse node module has a lot of node code, I would recommend people to use [envify](https://github.com/hughsk/envify) followed by [uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) to make their code more optimized.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Parse-module doesn't expose itself as a browser global. You should have a file, such as `app.js` that contains your definitions and use that to require the `Parse` module.

For example:

```
//app.js
var Parse = require("parse");
console.log(Parse)
```

Bundle it (the bundle will contain your app.js and the contents of the `parse`-module:

```
browserify ./app.js -o app.bundle.js
```

and include the bundled file to your `HTML` file

```
<script src="app.bundle.js"
```

After you open your `HTML` file, you should see the `Parse` object in your console.

Comment: Parse does expose the Parse method/class globally. Thanks anyway ;)